# relativedelta in Python 2.4

Tags: python, datetime

How can I get the month-ago date in Python 2.4?

In Python 2.5 it's easy:

```
onemonthago = datetime.date.today() + relativedelta(months = -1)
```

Answer (score 3):

`relativedelta` is a [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) function, and dateutil is python2.4 compatible, so you should be able to use the same if you have dateutil installed.